# Is there a way to set a layout for JOptionsPane.showOptionDialog?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, joptionpane

If the array you are using is, let's say a length of 15, and you want to display them all at once, it shows them side by side in a really long display box:

```
String[] options = {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4",
    "Option 5","Option 6","Option 7","Option 8","Option 9",
    "Option 10","Option 11","Option 12","Option 13","Option 14",
    "Option 15"};

int displayoptions = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (null, "select one", "Title",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options [0]);
```

Is there a way to display it so that it has a Flow Layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 15 options I'd do it more like this:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ManyOptions {

    ManyOptions() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        String[] options = {"Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4",
            "Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8", "Option 9",
            "Option 10", "Option 11", "Option 12", "Option 13", "Option 14",
            "Option 15"};

        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(options);
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null,
                combo,
                "Select One",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Selected Index: " + combo.getSelectedIndex());
        } else {
            System.out.println("choice cancelled..");
        }

        // old way, for comparison..
        int displayoptions = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
                null,
                "select one",
                "Title",
                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
                null,
                options,
                options[0]);
        System.out.println("displayoptions: " + displayoptions);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ManyOptions o = new ManyOptions();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to use a JPanel with a GridLayout, and display it in a modal JDialog (which is what a JOptionPane is in reality). For example,

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Foo1 {
   private static final int BUTTON_COUNT = 15;
   private static String selection = "";
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 0, 5, 5));
      panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
      for (int i = 0; i < BUTTON_COUNT; i++) {
         panel.add(new JButton(new ButtonAction("Option " + (i + 1))));
      }
      JDialog dialog = new JDialog(null, "Select One", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
      dialog.add(panel);
      dialog.pack();
      dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      dialog.setVisible(true);
      System.out.println("selection: " + selection);
   }

   private static class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ButtonAction(String name) {
         super(name);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         selection = e.getActionCommand();
         Component c = (Component) e.getSource();
         Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(c);
         win.dispose();
      }
   }
}
```